# Скрыть панель навигации в IOS

Tags: html, ios, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Посоветуйте способ, которым можно скрыть панель навигации на `iOS` устройствах, после полной загрузки страницы.

На скриншоте я обвёл эту панель красным.

[image: скриншоте]

Этот фича используется, например, в [мобильной версии VK](http://m.vk.com).

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать добавить специальные мета-теги.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />     
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes" />
```

Подробнее написано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440386/is-it-possible-hide-ios-browser-chrome-on-a-normal-webpage).

Другой вариант:

```
  window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
      // Hide the address bar!
      window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
  });
```

Comment: Не достигнуто желаемого эффектаю

Comment: Добавил в ответ второй вариант.